# NTP timestamp is not correctly parsed c++

Tags: c++, windows, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, ntp

I want to send an SNTP req and then parse the response, hence I started by simply creating a timestamp convert it to ntp and then try to read the seconds and the fractional part. The issue is that the seconds part is not correctly parsed in the first place, always shifted by a few seconds. This is what I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>    // Needed to perform IO operations
#include <ctime>

constexpr auto SECONDS_SINCE_FIRST_EPOCH = (2208988800ULL);
constexpr auto NTP_SCALE_FRAC = (4294967296ULL);

using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 

    std::time_t _timeEpoch = std::time(nullptr);
    unsigned long long tv_ntp, tv_usecs, tv_time;
    tv_ntp = _timeEpoch + SECONDS_SINCE_FIRST_EPOCH; 
    tv_usecs = (NTP_SCALE_FRAC * _timeEpoch) / 1000000UL;
    tv_time = (tv_ntp << 32) | tv_usecs;

    std::cout << "GetUtcTimeMilliSeconds UTC sec: " << _timeEpoch << " 1900: " << tv_ntp << " fraction of second " << tv_usecs << " tv_time " << tv_time << std::endl;

    uint32_t msw = (tv_time >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    uint32_t lsw = tv_time & 0xFFFFFFFF;

    std::cout << "GetUtcTimeMilliSeconds msw " << msw << " lsw: " << lsw << std::endl;  

    return 0; 
}
```

I expected msw to be equal to tv_ntp and lsw to tv_usecs but they are not

```
GetUtcTimeMilliSeconds UTC sec: 1572103823 1900: 3781092623 fraction of second 6752134505701 tv_time 16239671495839982821
GetUtcTimeMilliSeconds msw 3781093167 lsw: 445916389
```

Comment: Does NTP have a provision for leap seconds?

Comment: @markr As far as I am concerned NTP servers receive leap second announcements (e.g. GPS). However, in my example the timestamp is not correctly parsed even before sent to the server. Is it lack of precision or am I missing something else?

Comment: I only ask because I know GPS keeps leap seconds separate from the time, and if you're only a few seconds off something similar would explain the difference. Unfortunately I don't know enough about NTP itself.